# Passing set statehook function into subroute component. Destructuring error

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

Using `react` 18.2 with `react-router-dom` 6.3
I have my routes in this style

```
<Routes>
        <Route path="/" element = {<App/>}>
             <Route path="search" element = {<Content/>} />
             <Route path="nextComp/:id" element = {<Component/>} />
        </Route>
</Routes>
```

In my app, I have a dynamic nav bar that I want to stick around which could be used to select different generated components (generated by actions in the `Content` component in `/search`) There are states in my `App` component that need to be set by the `Content` component. I pass information down with something along the lines of:

```
const App: React.FC = () => {
    const [lock, setLock] = useState<Boolean>(false);
    const [lotsQuery, setLotsQuery] = useState<lotWaferQueryInput[]>([]);

    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const onClickHandle(() => {
        navigate('/search', {state: { 
            setLock : setLock,
            setLotsQuery: setLotsQuery
        }});
    }, []);
}
```

In my `Content` component, I try accessing the data with :

```
const {state} : any = useLocation();
const {setLock,setLotsQuery} : any = state;
```

This results in
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'setLock' of 'state' as it is null.` I understand that you can't directly serialize a function. How should I reapproach the way I'm routing data?

As of now, the hierarchy looks like

```
App
-Nav (child component)
-Content(search subroute)
-Component(nextComp subroute)
```

Data is entered in `Content`, and then sent to App (which is the current problem of being able to set function). Data is handled by `App` and then passed to nav and generates `Component`(subroutes)

How can I achieve sending data from a subroute component to a parent route then? Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The route state needs to be JSON serializable, so sending functions just won't work. I suggest exposing the functions down to nested routes via the [`Outlet`](https://reactrouter.com/en/v6.3.0/api#outlet)'s context and the [`useOutletContext`](https://reactrouter.com/en/v6.3.0/api#useoutletcontext) hook.

Example:

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const App: React.FC = () => {
  const [lock, setLock] = useState<Boolean>(false);
  const [lotsQuery, setLotsQuery] = useState<lotWaferQueryInput[]>([]);

  ...

  return (
    ...
      <Outlet context={{ setLock, setLotsQuery }} />
    ...
  );
};
```

In nested route's component:

```
import { useOutletContext } from 'react-router-dom';

...

const { setLock, setLotsQuery } = useOutletContext();
```

...

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/" element={<App />}> // <-- provides context value
    <Route path="search" element={<Content />} /> // <-- can access context value
    <Route path="nextComp/:id" element={<Component />} />
  </Route>
</Routes>
```